# Confusion about nested loops and array access

Tags: c++

I have some C++ I'm trying to port, and I'm confused about a couple lines and what exactly they're doing. The code is as follows. The variable *im* is a 2D float array of size num_rows by num_cols.

```
for(x=0; x < num_cols; x++){
   float *im_x_cp = im[1]+x; //(1)
   for(y = 1; y < num_rows; y++, im_x_cp+=num_cols){
      float s1 = *im_x_cp;
      //et cetera
   }
}
```

The code marked (1) is particularly confusing to me. What part of the 2d array *im* is this referencing?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Would you please include the actual declaration for `im`?

Comment: It's a handrolled class for representing binary images, but under the hood it's declared how you would expect.

Comment: It's a class? You're going to have to also show the declaration for `operator[]` and any associated overloads. I have learned not to expect the obvious.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`im[1]` is a pointer to an array of floats, that is, it's the second line/column of your matrix.
`im[1] + x` is a **pointer** to the element at coordinate (1,x) (recall how pointer arithmetic works) and `s1` is its value.

Comment: You think you understand pointers, then something like this makes you wonder if you know anything. Anyway, this makes perfect sense now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The type of `im[1]` is `float *`. So, according to the rules of C++ pointer arithmetic:

```
  float* im_x_cp = im[1];
  im_x_cp = im_x_cp + x;
```

Now it's a `float*` pointing to item '1+x' in that slice.